# regex - Exclude the line with the word (php)

Tags: php, regex

Help please, how can exclude the presence of a string if a certain word is present in it.

Example:

```
any text here my text any text word wrong any text
any text here my text any text true any text
any text here my text any text wrong any text
```

This regex marks all lines (https://regex101.com/r/rrgEp6/1):

```
here([a-z, ]{0,70})((?:(?! word))) (wrong|true)
```

It is required to exclude in this case the word - "word":

```
any text here my text any text true any text
any text here my text any text wrong any text
```

Comment: You want `here((?:(?!\bword\b)[a-z ,]){0,70}) (wrong|true) `, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/84mEES/2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
here((?:(?!\bword\b)[a-z ,]){0,70}) (wrong|true)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/84mEES/2)

**Details**

- `here` - a string
- `((?:(?!\bword\b)[a-z ,]){0,70})` - Group 1: a lowercase letter, space or comma, 0 to 70 occurrences, that does not start a `word` as a whole word char sequence
- - space
- `(wrong|true)` - Group 2: `wrong` or `true` char sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?!.*\bword\b).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rbkbet/1/).